# How to import fonts in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use some fonts and I want it to work without having this font on the client computer. I have done this but it doesn't work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: EntezareZohoor2;
    src: url(Entezar2.ttf) format("truetype");
}

.EntezarFont {
    font-family: EntezareZohoor2, B Nazanin, Tahoma !important;
}
```

Comment: `Embed` refers to inject the font source into the html, but not to just reference it.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Following lines are used to define a font in css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'EntezareZohoor2';
    src: url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.eot'), url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Following lines to define/use the font in css**

```
#newfont{
    font-family:'EntezareZohoor2';
}
```

Comment: the font-family property change to EntezarZohoor2 but it cannot loadd it

Comment: have you check the path of fonts available.

Comment: oh , I just have ttf file ... is it needed to have all formats ???? like eot or etc ???

Comment: Highly recommend http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator for converting fonts for web and generating the CSS.

Answer (score 31):

One of the best source of information on this topic is Paul Irish's [Bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) article.

Read it and you will end with something like:

```
/* definition */
@font-face {
  font-family: EntezareZohoor2;
  src: url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.eot');
  src: url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.eot?') format('☺'),
       url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/EntezareZohoor2.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* use */
body {
    font-family: EntezareZohoor2, Tahoma, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

When I went to Google fonts all they gave me were true type font files `.ttf` and didn't explain at all how to use the @font-face to include them into my document. I tried the web font generator from font squirrel too, which just kept running the loading gif and not working... I then found this site -

https://transfonter.org/

I had great success using the following method:

I selected the **Add Fonts** button, leaving the default options, added all of my `.ttf` that Google gave me for `Open Sans` (which was like 10, I chose a lot of options...).

Then I selected the **Convert** button.

**Heres the best part!**

They gave me a zip file with all the font format files I selected, `.ttf`, `.woff` and `.eot`. Inside that zip file they had a `demo.html` file that I just double clicked on and it opened up a web page in my browser showing me example usages of all the different css font options, how to implement them, and what they looked like etc.

**`@font-face`**

I still didn't know at this point how to include the fonts into my stylesheet properly using `@font-face` but then I noticed that this `demo.html` came with it's own stylesheet in the zip as well. I opened the stylesheet and it showed how to bring in all of the fonts using `@font-face` so I was able to quickly, and easily, copy paste **this** into my project -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-LightItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-LightItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-LightItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The `demo.html` also had it's own inline stylesheet that was interesting to take a look at, though I am familiar with working with font weights and styles once they are included so I didn't need it much. For an example of how to implement a font style onto an html element for reference purposes you could use the following method in a similar case to mine after `@font-face` has been used properly -

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.banner h1{
    font-size: 43px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.banner p{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Go through http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/ 

**Try this:**

```
  @font-face {
        font-family: 'EntezareZohoor2';
        src: url('EntezareZohoor2.eot');
        src: local('EntezareZohoor2'), local('EntezareZohoor2'), url('EntezareZohoor2.ttf') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
    }
```

Comment: the font-family property change to EntezarZohoor2 but it cannot loadd it

Comment: Did you check your path ? if the path is correct then check it with any other `font-family`.

Comment: yes
I have check the path it was correct , when i enter the path in browser it starts to download the font file

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/),[link2](http://bavotasan.com/2010/embedding-fonts-web-site-css-font-face/)

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'RieslingRegular';
        src: url('fonts/riesling.eot');
        src: local('Riesling Regular'), local('Riesling'), url('fonts/riesling.ttf')                       format('truetype');
    }
```

Comment: the font-family property change to EntezarZohoor2 but it cannot loadd it

Comment: when I enter the path in the browser addres bar it will download the font correctly so the path is correct

Answer (score 1):

I used Ataturk's font like this. I didn't use "TTF" version. I translated orginal font version ("otf" version) to "eot" and "woof" version.
Then It works in local but not working when I uploaded the files to server.
So I added "TTF" version too like this. Now, It's working on Chrome and Firefox but Internet Explorer still defence.
When you installed on your computer "Ataturk" font, then working IE too. But I wanted to use this font without installing.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ataturk';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('font/ataturk.eot');
    src: local('Ataturk Regular'), url('font/ataturk.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('font/ataturk.woff') format('woff');
}
```

You can see it on my website here: http://www.canotur.com

Comment: Hi again;
I added this below in second "src" part and it works now:
"url('font/ataturk.eot?iefix') format('opentype')"

You can check: www.canotur.com