# font not showing up on all browsers (micra font)

Tags: html, css

For some reason the font I'm using Micra is not showing up on all browsers. It works on all my browsers not when I test it on other people's browsers. Am I doing something wrong.

```
#nav {
position: fixed; 
top:55px;
left: 86px;
min-width:690px;
white-space:nowrap;
text-align:left;
padding:0 0 34px 333px;
z-index:99;
}

#nav a {    
font-family: Micra, serif;
color: #FFF;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:90%;
margin:0 55px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: use font-face to include the font

Comment: See also web fonts at http://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: The font is only installed in ur PC and not in others , That is way it is not working .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because they don't have that font installed.

If you have a license to embed the font, you can include it in your css file as follows

```
@font-face
{
 font-family: myFirstFont;
 src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-font-css) for more detailed how-to.

**update** here is a nice [list of free fonts that](http://www.google.com/fonts/) you can embed on your site.

Comment: I tried to look for a license for the font but couldn't find one

Comment: I can't find it anywhere to be bought only free downloads, embed it on your own risk. + read my last update. Don't forget to accept my answer  if you like it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this example :-

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet'         

type='text/css'>
```

visit this  [link](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Syntax)

see the overview part .

Answer (score 2):

Is the font installed on every computer you are testing it on?

If the Micra font isn't installed (and it doesn't sound familiar to me, so I assume it isn't) the browser will fall back to the default serif font.

Answer (score 2):

The use of Font family

The font-family property should hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.

so you use like

```
p{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
```

Otherwise you can use the font even if the other computer dont have the new fonts installed on machine like below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Micra;
    src: url('Micra.otf');
}
```

read [here](http://hallofhavoc.com/2010/09/how-to-use-font-face-css3/) more

Comment: So with   @font-face {
           font-family: Micra;
           src: url('Micra.otf');
          }   it' load the font to someones browser?