# Is it possible to get an outlined text effect using CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I use `Binner Di Regular` font.
Here are two example images. The first one shows an original `Binner Di Regular` font. The second one show the same font with Photoshop effects. So is it possible to get such an effect using CSS only? Or how can I get such a text other way then CSS?

Original `Binner Di Regular`:

[image]

`Binner Di Regular` with Photoshop effects:

[image]

Comment: you mean a [text shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow)?

Comment: Maybe can be possible . but have you tried something? Search about text-shadow. or Pseudo-elements

Comment: In future the (currently unsupported) `text-outline: 2px 2px #ff0000;` attribute could be invaluable.

Comment: You could also try [**this trick**](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-fonts-in-css

Comment: you might be able to achieve this effect with the tips from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css

Comment: You can combine different box-shadow layers in one style, so you can achieve different coloring. It's done like `text-shadow: properties, properties`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Webkit-only Solution

[image: Example]

In Webkit-based browsers we can make use of the `-webkit-text-stroke` and `-webkit-fill-color` properties alongside `text-shadow`.

This works in Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser and Chrome for Android ([Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke)).

```css
span {
  background: #D4D9D8;
  color: #3D463F;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 20px;
  
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  -webkit-fill-color: #3D463F;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
```

```html
<span>1234 567</span>
```

Comment: [**Here is an article on this approach.**](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use the [text-shadow CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

```css
div {
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 100px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
text-shadow: 2px 0px 0 #ccc, -2px 0 0 #ccc,3px 2px 0 #ccc,-2px -2px 0 #ccc,3px -2px 0 #ccc, 0px 2px #ccc, -2px 2px #ccc,3px 0px 0 #ccc,0 0 8px #000;
}
```

```html
<div>1234 567</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use text-shadow in this way :

```css
    p{
      font-size:50px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff,
        1px -1px 0px #fff,
        -1px -1px 0px #fff,
        -1px 1px 0px #fff,
        1px 1px 3px #000;
      background:grey;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 2em;
      }
```

```html
    <p>Text sample</p>
```

By adding multiples shadow, you can emulate a border on the text and adding a real shadow.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly possible through use of the [`text-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow) property

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html,body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:50px;
  text-shadow: 
    -1px -1px 0 #fff,
    1px -1px 0 #fff,
    -1px 1px 0 #fff,
    1px 1px 0 #fff;
  background:black;
  }
```

```html
hi. I'm not even in a div 1234567890
```

---

**Webkit browsers**

If you're only targeting webkit browsers, then you could make use of the [`-webkit-text-stroke-`](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) property.

---

Comment: That doesn't really resemble the image in the question, does it? You may want to update the offsets of the text shadow.