# Font Family Changes in other Computer's Browser

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

I have a div with  a `font-family: "Cooper Std Black";`. It looks like the image below:

[image]

But when I use another computer, same browser (Google Chrome/ both updated) the way it looks changes. What is happening? I had made sure that the cache of both browser is cleared.

[image]

Below is my CSS Code:

```
.myid_print_duo_college
{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 440px;
    color: #0C6A13;
    width: 304px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Cooper Std Black"; 
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;   
}
```

Comment: Did you include the font properly? Check for font path.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Cooper Std Black` isn't installed on the other computer. Maybe you installed this font manually on your computer. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-fonts-in-css) could help you on how to embed a font properly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your **Font** like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cooper Std Black';
    src: url('fonts/Cooper Std Black.eot'), url('fonts/Cooper Std Black.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Cooper Std Black.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can use this **Font** like below:

```
.myid_print_duo_college
{
    font-family:'Cooper Std Black';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please lead me where to download this kind of font. :)