# Font-face in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I decided to change the font of my page, with another downloaded from internet. I tried this way, but it doesn't work. The file "font.ttf" is in the same folder as the html file.

```
@font-face {
      font-family: Test;
      src: url(font.ttf);
}

header {
      font-family: Test;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 48px;
      background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Look into your console or network tab in the webdeveloper tools. Is the font successfully loaded?

Comment: make sure path is correct. @font-face {
      font-family: Test;
      src: url(../font.ttf);
}

Answer (score 0):

If your downloaded font has been saved in the main fonts folder on your system then you should just use it the same way as you would use any other font.

E.g.

```
font-family='New Font';
```

There should be no difference :)

Directory to the fonts folder; 
Control Panel > Appearance and Personalisation > Fonts > Add Font

Answer (score 0):

To add font to your website, you will need more than the font.ttf file.  Also, be as organized as possible from the start and don't just dump everything into one level.  Later, when more things are added, you may have a mess and it can get more confusing as things get more complicated. Neatly organize into folders.

1- You will need webfont extensions. Meaning, use an online generator to generate webfonts by submitting your .ttf file (make sure you follow the license allowance).  Those extensions work on different browsers.

2- You need to create a .CSS file for webfonts.  Here is a link for an example:
[link] [How to embed fonts in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-fonts-in-css)

3- You need to follow the exact path on how your fonts can be reached.

4- When you open up your .ttf file, pay attention to your font spelling. (this part can be tricky)

5- You will also need a .htaccess file that helps to link your web fonts to your site.  You may see your desired font on your local device browser but it may not work on another device that does not have that font installed.