# how to import font in webpage

Tags: css

here is my code
I had added font face but it is not applying

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('KellySlab.ttf') format('truetype');
   }
body, h1, h4, form,footer{font family: 'MyWebFont',sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed fonts in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-fonts-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are only loading a **.ttf** file, more formats are suggested for it to work on most browsers (like **woff**, **woff2**).

**Considering your case though:**

- I'd suggest you take advantage of google's CDN for that font family.
- You will avoid having to deal with extra font extensions.

See below:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Kelly Slab', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kelly+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<span>Testing Kelly Slab font-family</span>
```

**If you want to load it locally no matter what:**

Go to [font-squirrel.com](https://www.fontsquirrel.com), search for Kelly Slab and download the **.otf** file clicking here:

[image]

Once downloaded, upload your **.ot**f file to the [generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and download the generated web font kit which includes **woff** & **woff2**.

To load them:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('kellyslab-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('kellyslab-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

To use it:

```
selector {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great link that gives you more insight on the matter with really good examples [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

The @font-face rule should be added to the stylesheet before any styles.

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Then use it to style elements like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```