font-family is invalid in list
The font family of li in v-for is fine, but when I add an additional li element, the font family of the li element is using the font family of the system
I'm sure I've defined font-family correctly, because the li in v-for is normal, and only the single li is wrong
vue template:
<ul class="menu-list">
  <li
    v-for="(i, index) in ROUTES_INFO"
    :key="index"
    :class="{ active: active === index }"
    @click="swiper?.slideTo(index)"
  >
    <span class="menu-title">{{ i.meta.title }}</span>
    <div class="menu-subtitle">{{ i.meta.name }}</div>
  </li>
  <!-- this li font-family is broken -->
  <li>
    <span class="menu-title">充值中心</span>
    <div class="menu-subtitle">PAYMENT</div>
  </li>
</ul>

and css for li:
li {
  padding-left: vh(16);
  height: vh(72);
  width: vh(150);
  font-size: vh(18);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: RuiXian;
}

the result of debugging in chrome
But li, who is on the same level, has no problem
Normal font-family for li

You're lacking debug information. Have you used your browser's DOM inspector? It should reveal all.  Inspect the li and see what font-family is applied and what stylesheet the overriding style comes from.  you might find there's a conflicting style from somewhere in you app targeting nth-child li or something similar.

Try -    font-family: RuiXian !important;

@Михаил i tried !important,but it doesn't work

@yoduh I added an image of chrome debug results, and I'm sure no other styles are overwriting font-family

You need to inspect Import font. Are you properly doing this?
As a topic of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-import-fonts-in-css

@Михаил I'm pretty sure I introduced the font file because the font family of the circular li is correct and only the individual li is wrong

Ok. If you want font-family for Span and Div in Li. You may just create .my-font { font-family: RuiXian; } and  and further also/
And.... why Li - may be just DIV for single element ?

@Михаил It seems that the problem is not the code, but the font file I used is incomplete, and its Chinese font is only part of it. Sorry for not checking it carefully
